# How to add bookmark in iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, bookmarks

I have large image which is placed in UIImage with in the UIScrollView. I want to put Bookmark any particular point of image. How it is possible?

My App Structure

ScrollView
-ImageView
 -TestImage.png

Thank you.

Comment: @user532445 can you elaborate more on this ? putting bookmark on image means what ?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of approaches:

1) Composite the bookmark image directly onto your UIImage and update your UIImageView in your scroll view.

2) Add an overlay of your image as a view on top of the UIImageView. This is probably easist approach. In this approach, just get the touches point and create a new UIImageView containing the bookmark and addSubview it in the touches center point (or workout if the image is a pin, where the bottom of the pin should hit on the image).